# Vue dynamic component event bindings

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a dynamic component that is resolved and bound on runtime using the documented dynamic component syntax;

```
<div class="field">
    <component v-if="component" :is="component" @valueUpdated="onUpdate($event)"></component>
</div>
```

Decided using a prop assigned to on mounting.

For whatever reason, when the child component, rendered dynamically, emits an event `this.$emit('eventName', /*someData*/)` the parent does not seem to be able to hear it. Is the approach used in standard components applicable to those rendered dynamically? Props seem to work, so maybe I am not doing something correctly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

yeah you can use props with dynamic components it's just you need to use lowercase hyphenated (kebab-case) names for the html attribute, i.e.

```
<component v-if="component" :is="component" @value-updated="onUpdate"></component>
```

```js
  Vue.component('foo', {
  template: `
    <div>
          <button @click="$emit('value-updated', { bar: 'baz' })">pass data</button
        </div>
    `
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        currentComponent: 'foo',
        output: {},
    },
    methods: {
        onUpdate (payload) {
            this.output = payload
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <component v-if="currentComponent" :is="currentComponent" @value-updated="onUpdate"></component>
    <pre>{{ output }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: updated answer - not sure why I added the prop example as not relevant here - just make sure you use kebab case and emit the event name: `this.$emit('value-updated', { foo: 'bar' })`

Comment: Ah I see. So there is a translation between Camel and Kebab? About to try, so will mark as answer when try it out

Comment: could you please explain why there is v-if="component" in component ?

Comment: @KickButtowski I tweaked that to be `v-if="currentComponent"` which hopefully makes a little more sense in the example above, i.e. it tests there is a `currentComponent` string before trying to instantiate it